# In Scaladoc, how to link to a method in the same class?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scaladoc, intellij-scala

What is the correct way to create link to a method in the same class?
[Scaladoc documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/scaladoc.html) doesn't have examples of this.

Consider a class such as:

```
package controllers

// import ...

class AccountController extends Controller with Secured {

  def current = Authenticated() { request =>
    // ...
  }

  /**
   * See [[current]] for an endpoint that...
   */
  def findAll = Authenticated() { request =>
     // ... 
  }

}
```

In IntelliJ IDEA's "quick documentation" pop up, all these show up as red:

- `[[current]]`
- `[[#current]]`
- `[[AccountController.current]]`
- `[[AccountController#current]]`
- `[[controllers.AccountController.current]]`

[image]

This does show up as blue:

```
[[controllers.AccountController#current]]
```

So I suppose this is correct, but is there there no simpler yet correct way?

Comment: While the Scaladoc HTML rendering gets a beautification, I'm afraid the tool itself is still in a rather unsatisfying state. [This issue](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3695) suggests that still only fully qualified names are supported...

Answer (score 7):

The correct way for your example would be:

```
[[controllers.AccountController#current()]]
```

The empty parenthesis are necessary here for functions without parameters, despite you shouldn't add these in the code. You also have to use fully-qualified names everywhere, this means it should contain the package, class name, a hashtag and the method name.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure when was it fixed, but I am using IntelliJ IDEA version 2020.3, and it works for me:

```
/**
 * See [[current]] for an endpoint that...
 */
```

[image]